# use regular expressions to identify html form action tags

Tags: regex, sed, html-parsing

I am trying to sed -i to update all my html forms for url shortening. Basically I need to delete the .php from all the action="..." tags in my html forms.

But I am stuck at just identifying these instances. I am trying this testfile:

```
action = "yo.php"
action = 'test.php'
action='test.php'
action="upup.php"
```

And I am using this expression:

```
grep -R "action\s?=\s?(.*)php(\"|\')" testfile
```

And grep returns nothing at all.

I've tried a bunch of variations, and I can see that even the \s? isn't working because just this grep command also returns nothing:

```
 grep -R "action\s?=\s?" testfile
grep -R "action\\s?=\\s?" testfile
```

(the latter I tried thinking maybe I had to escape the \ in \s).

Can someone tell me what's wrong with these commands?

Edit:

Fix 1 - apparently I need to escape the question make in \s? to make it be perceived as optional character rather than a literal question mark.

Comment: Quoted don't have any special meaning in regular expressions, they don't need to be escaped.

Comment: @Barmar that can't be true because otherwise my quotes will close my string. I am doing this in bash.

Comment: Yes, you need to escape the double quote to prevent it from closing the string. That has nothing to do with it being in a RE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using it, `grep` accepts basic posix regex syntax. The single quote does not need to be escaped in it<sup>1</sup>, but some of the metacharacters you use do -- in particular, `?`, `()`, and `|`. You can use

```
grep -R "action\s\?=\s\?\(.*\)php\(\"\|'\)" testfile
```

I recommend, however, that you use extended posix regex syntax by giving `grep` the `-E` flag:

```
grep -E -R "action\s?=\s?(.*)php(\"|')" testfile
```

As you can see, that makes the whole thing much more readable.

**Addendum:** To remove the .php extension from all action attributes in a file, you could use

```
sed -i 's/\(action\s*=\s*["'\''][^"'\'']*\)\.php\(["'\'']\)/\1\2/g' testfile
```

Shell strings make this look scarier than it is; the sed code is simply

```
s/\(action\s*=\s*["'][^"']*\)\.php\(["']\)/\1\2/g
```

I amended the regex slightly so that in a line `action='foo.php' somethingelse='bar.php'` the right `.php` would be removed. I tried to make this as safe as I can, but be aware that handling HTML with sed is [always hacky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Combine this with `find` and its `-exec` filter to handle a whole directory.

<sup>1</sup> And that the double quote needs to be escaped is because you use a doubly-quoted shell string, not because the regex requires it.

Comment: you are not selecting the quotes before the filename, and instead of `("|')` which is used to OR words like in `(big|small)` if you check for single chars it is more common to use char groups `["']` - so for the it should read `[\"'](.*)\.php[\"']` to select the filename only

Comment: Since `grep` gives matching lines, that the first quote is matched by `.*` rather than explicitly is unlikely to be critical. `[\"']` is better style, that is true, and it's also not necessary to have the `.*` in a capturing group. Could use `action=\s?=\s?[\"'].*\.php[\"']`.

Answer (score 0):

try this **unescaped plain regex**, which only selects text within quotes:

```
action\s?=\s?["'](.*)\.php["']
```

you can fiddle around here:

https://regex101.com/r/lN8iG0/1

so on **command line** this would be:

```
grep -P "action\s?=\s?[\"'](.*)\.php[\"']" test
```

Comment: You need to escape the double quote for the shell, but not the single quote.

Comment: the first line is ONLY the regex (as used in regex fiddler) the command line version is below

Comment: I wrote my comment before you added the second line

Comment: @Barmar ah, ok you meant the command line - i knew there, was to lazy to edit afterwards, but did on your command :)

Comment: i used the plain regex at first, mainly because i also wanted to point out the really fancy regex101.com tool for playing around with regex

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `-P` option to use Perl regexs:

```
$ grep -P "action\s?=\s?(.*)php(\"|\')" test
action = "yo.php"
action = 'test.php'
action='test.php'
action="upup.php"
```